# Android анимация и её различия

Tags: java, android, анимация

Всем привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем  может быть проблема? Не могу понять:

Мне надо запустить движение кнопок (тестово их 5, потом много), если запускаю так:

```
pr1.animate().translationYBy(-5000).setDuration(5000);
```

то без проблем срабатывает код нажатия.

Если запускаю анимацию так:

```
 final Animation Pusk = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pusk);
          pr1.startAnimation(Pusk);
```

То анимация происходит, но нажать на кнопку получается только в её начальном положении. Согласно анимации она уезжает в нужную точку, но в начальном месте остается, как-бы её "фантом", на котором срабатывает нажатие.

Обработка нажатия:

```
public void Catch1(View v){
       ListWords.add(pr1.getText().toString());
       texx.setText(String.valueOf(ListWords));
    }
```

Comment: Да, это старый известный "баг"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Старые средства анимации

Классы из пакета android.view.animation (не путайте с более новым пакетом android.animation, появившимся в Honeycomb).
Это **устаревшая** инфраструктура анимации, о которой следует знать в основном для того, чтобы избегать ее. Если в имени класса присутствует слово «animaTION» вместо «animaTOR», это верный признак того, что перед вами старый инструмент и пользоваться им не следует.

Пример с ObjectAnimator:

```
   ObjectAnimator moveAnimatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourBtn, "y", -5000);
   moveAnimatorY.setDuration(5000);
   moveAnimatorY.start();
```